# How to get relative paths with Pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I started using `from pathlib import Path` in place of `os.path.join()` to concatenate my paths. Taking the following code into consideration:

```
from pathlib import Path
import cv2

rootfolder = "rootyrooty"
file = "alittlefile"
image_path = Path(rootfolder, file)
image = cv2.imread(image_path.as_posix())
```

I'm using `image_path.as_posix()` to get a full string so I can pass `image_path` into `imread` function. Directly typing `image_path` doesn't works since it returns `WindowsPath('rootyrooty/alittlefile')` but I need `"rootyrooty/alittlefile"` (Since `imread` accepts strings instead of windowsPath objects). Do I have to use another component from `pathlib` instead of `Path` so I can just feed `image_path` into `imread` function. Like:

```
from pathlib import thefunctionyetidontknow
image_path = thefunctionyetidontknow("rootyrooty","alittlefile")
print("image_path")
# returns "rootyrooty/alittlefile"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are combining paths is perfectly fine.
What is questionable is the usage of `as_posix()` on a Windows machine. Some libs that accept a string as a path may be fine with posix path separators, but it may be preferable to use the os separator instead. To get path with filesystem separators, use `str`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

> The string representation of a path is the raw filesystem path itself (in native form, e.g. with backslashes under Windows), which you can pass to any function taking a file path as a string:
>
> ```
> >> p = PurePath('/etc')
> >> str(p)
> '/etc'
> >> p = PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files')
> >> str(p)
> 'c:\\Program Files'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `Path` object to a string with Python's builtin `str` function:

```
from pathlib import Path
import cv2

rootfolder = "rootyrooty"
file = "alittlefile"
image_path = Path(rootfolder, file)
image = cv2.imread(str(image_path))
```